# OpenCV: accessing pixel intensity values of type 8UC4

Tags: opencv, c++11

Anyone knows which method is needed to be invoked to access the RGB value of a picture of the type 8UC4  (8 bits per component, 4 channels (color channels + alpha)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`mat.at(i, j)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#mat-at), to access the pixel located at `i` row and `j` column, But `at()` must be used with data type of `Mat`, which is passed as a template type. OpenCV won't throw any error if you use wrong data type, instead it would return some garbage, so you need to take care of that thing, single channel matrix pixels can be accessed as `mat.at<uchar>(i, j)`, `mat.at<float>(i, j)`.

For multi-channel matrices, you need to use `cv::Vec3b`, `cv::Vec3f`, `cv::Vec4b`, etc.

In your case, since it is a 4-channel uchar matrix, its pixel values can be accessed as:

```
cv::Vec4b pixVal = mat.at<cv::Vec4b>(0, 0);
```